# Hide window from taskbar vb.net and alt+tab via WindowHandle

Tags: vb.net, handle

I have the window handle of another application and I want to remove it from the windows taskbar. I'd also like to remove it from the alt-tab menu. The window is a chrome app running my webpage, and I've experimented and I can effect it with MoveWindow successfully.

I just need to know how to declare the APIs to do this, if it's possible and how please :D

Thank you StackExchange!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all this got is 1 measly downvote, I managed to create a work around. I simple set the window state to hide or show using its handle.